# Why smbprotocol connection is getting timeout

Tags: python, smb

I'm trying to transfer some file from ubuntu to Window(AWS EC2 instance).But I'm getting following error.

```
ValueError: Failed to connect to '35.154.105.236': timed out
```

For reference

```
import smbclient
import sys

# Optional - register the credentials with a server
print(smbclient.register_session("35.154.105.236", username="Administrator", password="XXXXXXXXXXX"))
```

May I know what is missing and why it is getting timeout.

Comment: Wrong IP? Blocked ports? Have you tried pinging that IP, or telnet to that port?

Comment: SMB isn't some strange protocol either. If it's enabled, you can connect to a file share from any OS. On Windows, you just use a UNC path with the IP instead of a server name. With other OSs you mount the path as a drive. Have you tried that? If you can't get that to work, Python won't work either

Comment: IP is just fake in the question

Comment: I'm able to create the EC2 instance in ubuntu system

Comment: In your assumption what should be the problem ?

Comment: My source is ubuntu & destintation is windows

Comment: How to enable SMB

Comment: Just google `Ubuntu SMB` or `Linux SMB`. The first results point to guides and tutorials

Comment: I'm trying to implement it using python

Comment: If you can't visit a site with a browser, you can't visit it with curl or Python. If you can't mount a file share (whether NFS or SMB), you can't connect to it with code. A timeout most likely means there's a networking issue that no amount of code is going to fix. To test that, just mount the file share